# Keyup functionality defect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have passed the value of *textbox* to *ajax* using ***keyup()***. But on emptying the textbox it displays all the contents from the relative table. I want an empty page while the textbox is empty. Can anyone help me with this problem. The codes are:

```
$('.form-control').keyup(function () {
    var name = $('#member_search').val();
    var phone = $('#member_contact').val();
    var father = $('#member_father').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "search_result.php",
        data: {
            name: name,
            contact: phone,
            father: father
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether any one has content else empty the result box

```
$('.form-control').keyup(function () {
    var name = $('#member_search').val();
    var phone = $('#member_contact').val();
    var father = $('#member_father').val();
    if (name || phone || father) {//use name && phone && father if you want to make sure all inputs has content
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "search_result.php",
            data: {
                name: name,
                contact: phone,
                father: father
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#result').html('');
    }
});
```